# Read filenames from a file and update another file with the status

Tags: shell

I have a text file `abc.txt`, it contains some file names.

I have to write a shell script which checks whether the files names listed in `abc.txt` exists or not in the directory.

Then create a new file, which contains file name with status 'Exists' or 'Not Exists'.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Please do not tag your question with [tag:unix], if it is really about shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like:

```
while read line
do
    if [[ -f $line ]]
    then
         echo "File $line exists"
    else 
         echo "Creating file $line"
         touch $line
    fi
done < abc.txt
```